# Delete all text after certain word in wordpress post via mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have thousand of posts in wordpress which I want to delete all content after certain word say 【Delivery Date】 via mysql?

example of post:
【product】
Baby toy 1
【Delivery Date】
12 Dec,2017
【Term】
xxxxxx xxxxxx

wiil be delete part:
【Delivery Date】
12 Dec,2017
【Term】
xxxxxx xxxxxx

Thanks

Comment: post the query that you have so far, and try to fix the formatting of this question. I don't even know where to start

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a [regular expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) to search and replace the content after the word.

There are a couple of solutions I can think of with mysql.

1. Export all the data and use php or other tool to search and replace the content using regular expressions then import back into mysql
2. If you can build a User Defined Function into mysql then this will do what you want https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp with one query or you can build your own function similar to this https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/